# Unity3d load all textures or load on demand?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple question, however, I am a bit puzzled. I have a coloring game and thus I have around `50` images each at `2048 x 2048`. Should I best load them all onto a gameobject at the beginning of the game to reference later in the game, or should I instantiate one at a time from resourses? What seems the best idea?

Side note, I need small icons of each image in the gallery to display what it looks like

Comment: nah, just load them one at a time when you need them from `Resources.Load`.  Google

Comment: and for the icons I should simply have small images I guess?

Comment: that's correct.  simply make the icons using Affinity or whatever.

Comment: There is insufficient detail for a meaningful answer.  Totally depends on the nature of your game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the provided information, I would suggest you create separate preview/thumbnail images, using your art people/program/whatever, and load those when in your gallery. Then, load the full sized images as they are needed (and release them when they aren't).

[See Unity's Art Asset Best Practice Guide (A lot of 3D, but Textures in particular applys to 2D).](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ArtAssetBestPracticeGuide.html)